# Sharepoint 2013 adding item from list to calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a simple custom list which takes a Person name (Title), and Date and Time. I want to add this Date and Time to the calendar on the same site. I created a workflow and it looks like its working but its creating the same event about 200+ times. Could this be because Im setting the start time and end time to the same? Is my workflow correct?

Workflow:
[image]

Same Start Time and End Time:

[image]

Creating even 200+ times for the same day:

[image]

Custom list:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the **Transition to stage** to **Go to End of Workflow**

[image]

why is sharepoint so unorthodox!